# How to use slickGoTo for sliding directly to an non adjacent slide without seeing all the slides in between?

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I am using a slick slider which shows one slide as active. I can use the arrows to navigate between the slides What i am looking for is a way to go to a particular slide directly from the current slide without sliding all the slides in between.. For example if I am going from slide 1 to slide 4 using slickGoTo now it slides like 1..2..3..4 .. What i want is to go from 1 directly to 4 just like 1..4 witout sliding through 2 and 3.

[See this codepen](https://codepen.io/unni_27/pen/VEEBEe)

```
$('.sl1').slick("slickGoTo", 4);
```

In short what i want is to make going from 1 to 4 look exactly like going from 1 to 2..

Comment: Temporarily reduce the slider speed number to normal speed / x where x is number of slides in between. E.g. 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point about sliders. Its like a carousel, where you have to pass every element on order to get to the others. However when you change set `fade: true` in slick initialization you will get your desired result (without sliding).

```
$('.sl1').slick({
  initialSlide: 0,
  autoplay: false,
  arrows:true,
  fade: true
});
```

https://codepen.io/niklasp-the-looper/pen/JmmmKO